# Inject entity repository as dependency in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have a Symfony project where I want to inject an entity repository into a service. The service definition is in XML format.

```
        <service id="vendorname_shop.checkout_data_manager" class="Vendorname\ShopBundle\Checkout\CheckoutDataManager">
            <argument type="service" id="security.token_storage" />
            <argument type="service" id="session" />
            <argument type="service" id="vendorname_shop.repository.pickup_point" />
            <argument type="service" id="vendorname_shop.repository.order_payment_method" />
            <argument type="service" id="vendorname_shop.repository.billing_address" />
        </service>
```

I'd like to make `vendorname_shop.repository.billing_address` service to be a simple entity repository (not a custom class that I wrote, but the result of

`EntityManager->getRepository(Vendorname\ShopBundle\Entity\BillingAddress::class)`

method call), so I used the factory syntax in the xml, but I keep recieving error messages when Symfony tries to evaluate the argument:

```
        <service id="vendorname_shop.repository.billing_address" class="Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository">
            <factory service="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" method="getRepository" />
            <argument type="expression">Vendorname\ShopBundle\Entity\BillingAddress::class</argument>
        </service>
```

The code above gives me `Unexpected character "\" around position 11.`

Comment: First off, drop the ::class portion because you are already giving a fully qualified class name.  This is just a guess (I normally use yaml) but try doubliing up your back slashes. Vendorname\\ShopBundle etc

Comment: You are absolutely right, I don't need the ::class, just needed to change the argument type to string as well and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
services:
    my_service_name:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\MyServiceName
        arguments: ["@=service('doctrine.orm.entity_manager').getRepository('AppBundle:MyEntity')"]
```

Then you have build a service for your repository.

```
public function __construct(MyEntityRepository $repository) {
    $this->repository = $repository;
}
```

But i think there are a lot more possibilities.

http://www.zuellich.de/blog/2016/03/symfony-3-inject-entity-repository-into-service-controller.html

here is another solution. I've replaced my answer with some of that solution it is a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

As Cerad said, if I use a fully qualified name, the `::class` is totally useless!
In addition changing the argument type to string solved the problem!

```
<argument type="string">Vendorname\ShopBundle\Entity\BillingAddresss</argument>
```